How to get a Cursor from Room in a coroutine?
Trying to get this cursor:
@Query("SELECT * FROM category")
fun getCursor() : Cursor

with this code:
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            binding.category.adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(
                context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                RoomDB.getInstance(context).categories().getCursor(),
                arrayOf("label"),
                arrayOf(android.R.id.text1).toIntArray(),
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER
            )
        }

Which yields this exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread...

Clearly, I'm not accessing the database from the main thread (note the lifecycleScope.launch). Maybe I have to make getCursor suspend?
Easy enough, but this yields weird compile time errors:

Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type). - android.database.Cursor


error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (android.database.Cursor).


public abstract java.lang.Object getCursor(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

What is going on here?

"Clearly, I'm not accessing the database from the main thread" -- that depends entirely on the implementation of lifecycleScope. If its default dispatcher is Dispatchers.main or Dispatchers.main.immediate, then you would be accessing that code on the main application thread.

The code above comes from a static method called from a fragments someView.onClickListener method. But I take it from your comment that my assumption that everything in a launch block would be executed in parallel was wrong.

launch doesn't necessarily do work on a different thread. In this case, it uses the main thread. A launched coroutine allows you to run code that includes suspend functions. Suspend functions will use other threads under the hood and temporarily release the current thread until they return (which is where parallelism will occur). This is why lifecycleScope.launch by default uses the main thread. In most cases, that is what you want because so many Android classes in the UI demanded to be worked with on the main thread only.

It seems that Cursor just doesn't play nice with suspend. I went only for a Cursor, because the CursorAdapter was mentioned in the Spinner guide, in case the choices for the Spinner come from a database. But there is no actual need for a Cursor.
This just works absolutely fine:
@Query("SELECT * FROM category")
suspend fun getAll() : List<Category>

and
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        binding.categories.adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            RoomDB.getInstance(requireContext()).categories().getAll()
        )
    }


lifecycleScope.launch does not put you in the IO thread, you are just in a coroutine scope at that point but on the main thread
create a separate method that runs the query in IO context
suspend fun getData(): Cursor = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    return RoomDB.getInstance(context).categories().getCursor()
}

lifecycleScope.launch {
    val cursor = getData()
        binding.category.adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(
            context,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
            cursor,
            arrayOf("label"),
            arrayOf(android.R.id.text1).toIntArray(),
            CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER
        )
    }

Alternatively adding suspend to the room query should do it too but you seem to have been missing a basic understanding of how coroutines work

I admit to a rather superficial understanding of coroutines. "adding suspend to the room query should do it too": Any idea why I'm getting these weird errors then?

We would need to see your whole entity class to say why. The error seems to be about the constructor, not that you marked the function to suspend. Marking it suspend at the source should be the preferred solution for code simplicity.

When you launch a new coroutine it will be executed asynchronously. That doesn't necessarily mean it is also done concurrently (or in parallel), though.
If there is just one single thread you can still launch multiple coroutines that won't wait for one another to finish (that's what asychronicity is all about), but since there is only one thread, only one of the coroutines will be running at any given time and all others are blocked in the meantime. The UI is an example of that. Everything that is displayed must run on that single UI thread. Usually the main thread is used for the UI.
It is important that everything you run on the main thread will only run for a short time. That's necessary so that the UI stays responsive: When there is a long running operation blocking the main thread, no user input (a button click f.e.) can be handled until that operation finishes. Also, no UI updates can be made during that time, like animations. The UI will freeze. When a function terminates quickly it is called main safe in that it can be safely called on the main thread, without blocking other important operations. Just to reiterate: There is only one main thread and only one piece of code can be run on that thread at any given time. You can always launch new coroutines on that thread, but they will only run when no other coroutines are occupying that thread. They will NOT run concurrently to other coroutines.
There are some ways that a long-running coroutine can make itself main-safe by voluntarily returning the control of the thread and waiting until the coroutine is resumed again. In the meantime other queued coroutines can be executed on the thread so it isn't unnecessarily blocked.
Now, to your error message:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread...

To prevent accidental blocking of the main thread some APIs refuse to run when they detect that they are called from the main thread. When you launch a new coroutine the current thread is also used for this new coroutine. Until specified otherwise that will be the main thread. What you need is to switch your coroutine to another thread.
Now, that's where concurrency comes into play. When you launch your coroutine on another thread, that coroutine is run in parallel to the main thread. This new thread can also only run one coroutine at any given time, but that one coroutine runs at the same time as the currently running coroutine on the main thread.
With coroutines you usually don't select specific threads for your coroutine to run on, instead you can specify a Dispatcher that will assign your coroutine to an appropriate thread. You will probably only need these three dispatchers:

Dispatchers.Main: This dispatcher will always use the main thread. Use for your UI.
Dispatchers.IO: This dispatcher has a large thread pool at its disposal that expects its threads to have very low load and wait most of the time. This should be used for file system or network access where the most time is spent waiting for a resource to return data.
Dispatchers.Default: This dispatcher has a few threads available that can be used for potentially long running computations that should leverage the most CPU power that it can get.

You can choose the dispatcher when you launch a new coroutine like this:
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)

You can even move some code of your already running coroutine to another dispatcher by wrapping it in
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // ...
}

Kotlin provides an easy way for you to determine if a certain function must be executed in a coroutine. Such functions are prepended with the suspend modifier. Calling a suspend function can only be done from a launch block or from another suspend function. This will not start a new coroutine though, it will just inherit the coroutine context and scope of the caller so you can, for example, use withContext and several other coroutine-specific functions. suspend functions are neither asynchronous nor concurrent, they are just simple functions that can only be called when your code already is running in a coroutine.

Wow. Thank you very much for this comprehensive explanation. I think I have a better understanding now of the relationship between coroutines and threads.

I have often written something like this: lifecycleScope.launch { /* database access */ }. How does this work then without specifying a dispatcher? I have two ideas: The coroutine automatically switches the call to the database suspend function to another thread; or, accessing the database is allowed from the main thread, as long as it happens in a coroutine, possibly because the call may be interrupted or so. Am I on to something here?
